# I think I've resolved dependency, rpm doesn't

Tags: centos, rpm, epel

I have upgraded EPEL repo in order to install Remi repository in order to upgrade PHP to 3.5.4 in order to upgrade civicrm (on a CentOS 6.7 VPS running one production site and its dev site).

repolist:

```
repo id          repo name                                         status
base             CentOS-6 - Base                                    6,575
epel             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64     12,126
extras           CentOS-6 - extras                                  52
updates          CentOS-6 - Updates                                 1,472
repolist: 20,225
```

but `rpm -Uvh remi-release-6.rpm` gives

```
warning: remi-release-6.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 00f97f56: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        epel-release >= 6 is needed by remi-release-6.6-2.el6.remi.noarch
```

Other than the fact that I have to find and install a GPG key for Remi, why is version 6 failing a dependency which says GE 6?

Comment: What is the output of `rpm -qa|grep epel-release`?

Comment: blank - just another system prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that you have installed the EPEL repositories by simply hand-editing an appropriate file in `/etc/yum.repos.d`.  That is perfectly OK in terms of getting the EPEL packages onto your system, but for more sophisticated usage it falls down a bit.

The REMI software knows that it needs EPEL packages, so the installation is made dependent on those being configured in.  The [recommended way to enable the EPEL packages](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F) on your system is to install the `epel-release` RPM.  This contains the relevant GPG key, the yum repo file, and not much else - but its presence is a quick way for packages to know that EPEL packages will be available if needed.

If you do install the `epel-release` RPM, then not only will your system be able to access EPEL packages, as it already can, but *other software packages will know that they can rely on EPEL's availability*, which they currently cannot.

Comment: This time I got an error from yum: `Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : epel-release-6-8.noarch                                      1/1
Error unpacking rpm package epel-release-6-8.noarch
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6;56f90482: cpio: open
  Verifying  : epel-release-6-8.noarch                                      1/1

Failed:
  epel-release.noarch 0:6-8` - not sure if that happened previously but I missed seeing the "failed" because of the complete following. Is this saying that the preexisting key is in the way?

Comment: Do you already have a file `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6`, and if so, how did it get there?

Comment: Yes - I downloaded it from Fedoraproject and installed it as an earlier rpm command failed because there was no key.

Comment: Try removing it before installing the `epel-release` RPM.

Comment: I have removed it, verified it gone and still get the same error. I also loosened permissions on that directory, as I had been unable to save a file there directly from nano (as root - "invalid argument") - ended up saving it elsewhere and using mv

Comment: I really don't understand this.  You're doing all this as root, right?  Is it possible that your system has some kind of crazily-restrictive `selinux` permissions set?  At any rate, I think this is turning into a completely new question, to wit: why can't I install the `epel-release` RPM?  I've told you why RPM doesn't think the EPEL packages are available, which is what you originally asked.  You might want to consider putting this question to bed, by accepting my answer (click the tick), and writing a new question about your installation problems (possibly pointing to this one for context).

Comment: *has 3 minute crash course on selinux* - sestatus reports that selinux is disabled.

Comment: I shall put myself to bed and restate the question in the morning - thanks :-)